# Is there a way to find which version of python my Kodi installation is using?

Tags: kodi

I'm new to Kodi and I installed Kodi 19.0 However, I'm trying to install an add-on with `xbmc.python` which is version `3.0` but it fails with error the requirement can't be satisfied.

How can I determine the python version that my Kodi has and replace it on the `addon.xml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kodi 19 is always python 3, all versions before that will be python 2.

Comment: Sure. But why do I get the error `The dependency on xbmc.python version 3 could not be satisfied` ?

Comment: Correct import would be `<import addon="xbmc.python" version="3.0.0"/>` best would be to share the addon/repo/addon.xml